# MongoDB shell version v3.6.4

Tags: mongodb, nosql

```
MongoDB shell version v3.6.4
```

connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2018-09-25T10:40:02.677+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017 after 5000ms milliseconds, giving up.
2018-09-25T10:40:02.677+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed